# Error al importar un módulo en Python : ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, packages, modulos

Tengo un problema al importar un modulo dentro de un módulo en un paquete .py, a continuación muestro el orden de jerarquía de los archivos

```
contenedor/
    paquete_1/
        __init__.py
        codigo.py
    modulo.py
```

Acá están los códigos de los módulos

```py
# > modulo.py
def funcion():
    pass
```

```py
# > codigo.py
from ..modulo import funcion
```

Al momento de ejecutar el archivo `código.py` me devuelve este error.

> **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

¿Cuál es la solución a esto?